# How do I get rows with max values across two columns

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group, netezza

I would like to know how to filter down a table by getting the max values from two columns. Here is a simplified input table. I want one row per person which has the max(year) and max(version)

| Name | Year | Version | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2017 | 1 | 100 |
| a | 2018 | 4 | 101 |
| a | 2018 | 5 | 102 |
| b | 2017 | 1 | 201 |
| b | 2017 | 2 | 202 |
| b | 2017 | 3 | 203 |
| b | 2016 | 2 | 204 |

What I want to get back is the rows with the highest years and then the rows with the highest years and the highest versions.

| Name | Year | Version | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2018 | 5 | 102 |
| b | 2017 | 3 | 203 |

I used the following code and got a table with the latest years. But I have multiple entries for each year with different version numbers. How do I weed it down further with just the latest version numbers.

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.YEAR, A.VERSION, A.VALUE
FROM TABLE A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT NAME, MAX(YEAR) AS YEAR
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY NAME
) B ON A.NAME = B.NAME AND A.YEAR = B.YEAR
```

Thank you.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Provided version only grow depending on year use `Max(version)` instead of `MAX(YEAR)`. Otherwise edit your question to tell us what is the desired result when those max 's are in different rows.

Comment: @serg user b has version 2 in 2016 _and_ 2017.

Comment: @Salman,  well  I should say 'not decreasing' instead of 'only grow' .  The point is under the condition the Max(version) row is always the MAX(YEAR) row too.

Comment: @serg see sample data and expected result.

Comment: Suppose the last sample row is `b 2016 9 204`.  What is the desired ouput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance aside, this generic SQL should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    -- select rows for that person-year-version
    -- where year is greater or (year is same and version is greater)
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE x.Name = t.Name AND (
        x.Year > t.Year OR (
            x.Year = t.Year AND x.Version > t.Version
        )
    )
)
```

If window (analytic) functions are available then just use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Year DESC, Version DESC) AS rn
    FROM t
) AS x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I am using IBM/Netezza. 

The version numbers increases each year and then resets to 1 and then increases again. 

For each individual I need one row, that represents the highest version number of the highest year.  I will try the solution you posted. Thanks.